# Enable/Disable Array element from another Array c#

Tags: c#, arrays

i would like to know how can i changes values from an array (float) depending another array (float).
Example :
the first array  is {1,2,3,4,5,6} and the second is {0,1,0,0,1,1}.
I would like the first array to show values only if the corresponding element in the second array is a "1", else "0".
so the result expecting is : {0,2,0,0,5,6}.

Any help please ?

Comment: What did you try? Shouldn´t be that difficult to iterate the first array and access its correspconding element at the same index within the other array.

Comment: Hi Sam, Welcome to Stackoverflow. Nice question. Can you please show your attempt?

Comment: Hint: a good approach is to use a dictionary. Any other way will work too. This should not be that hard

Comment: define "show"; arrays don't do anything except hold data - where are you showing this?

Comment: @panoskarajohn that is a different scenario, IMO

Comment: Can you please explain why especially the second array has the type "float"? If it shall only be 1 or 0, then bool would be much better. Float can be hard to compare, even int would be better. So what if an element in the second array is 0.99 or 0.5?

Comment: the second array can be Bool of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can multiply each value of the first array with the value of the second array. This will result in becoming 0 when your second array is 0 and the value from your first array when your second array is 1. You can do this either with a loop:

```
float[] first = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
float[] second = {0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1};

float[] result = new float[first.Length];

for(int i = 0; i < first.Length; i++)
 {
 result[i] = first[i] * second[i];
 }
```

Or with LINQ:

```
float[] first = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
float[] second = {0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1};

float[] result = first.Select((v,i) => v * second[i]).ToArray();
```

Don't forget to check whether your two arrays have the same length!

Answer (score 2):

Arrays don't hide or show anything - they are just piles of data. If you don't need to preserve the old values, you could just overwrite all the hidden data with zeros, but otherwise you'll need to do the projection yourself. This could be done when manually building a UI display, or it could be done by creating a *new* array that has the filtered/shown values in it; for example:

```cs
static void Main()
{
    float[] values = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
    bool[] mask = { false, true, false, false, true, true };

    var result = Filter(values, mask);
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", result));
}

static T[] Filter<T>(T[] values, bool[] mask)
{
    var arr = new T[values.Length];
    for(int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
    {
        arr[i] = mask[i] ? values[i] : default;
    }
    return arr;
}
```

Note I'm using `bool` instead of `float` here because `float` is a bad idea for a true/false scenario. A `bool[]` is *also* a pretty inefficient way of expressing this scenario, but... it'll do for now, for simplicity.

Comment: SomeBody method is faster, but your method works too! thanks for help

Comment: @Sam if performance is your aim, this would vectorize very nicely, but that's a much more advanced topic...

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with `.Zip()` in `System.Linq.Enumerable`

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    float[] a = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    float[] b = { 0, 1, 0, 0, 1 };

    float[] c = a.Zip(b, (x, y) => y == 1 ? x : 0).ToArray();
    // c = {0, 2, 0, 0, 5}
}
```

The advantage of `.Zip()` is that it can work with non numeric arrays for the condition.

```
public enum Respose
{
    Yes,
    No
}
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        float[] a = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
        Respose[] b = { Respose.No, Respose.Yes, Respose.No, Respose.No, Respose.Yes };

        float[] c = a.Zip(b, (x, y) => y == Respose.Yes ? x : 0).ToArray();
        // c = { 0, 2, 0, 0, 5 }
    }
}
```